# Omniture s_code.js version Upgrade

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I am working in a project where omniture tracking is implemented and it works fine without any issues.
We have a new requirement in project that states, we need to replace the existing library file s_code.js(Version H22) with the new s_code.js(VersionH26)
This library file has been provided by our adobe consultant.

I am being asked to find out the impact of this upgraded file on our project. Depending on the impact we need to decide whether we should accept this requirement or not.

For testing purpose I already replaced s_code.js with a new version in my local system. I checked for javascript errors. Everything seems to be good.

Posted this question just to make sure, if there is anything I need to verify specifically apart from javascript errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to, you can go through the [release notes](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/whatsnew/#Marketing_Cloud_Release_Notes) to find out what has changed from H22 to H26, but there shouldn't be any issues or things to consider from the upgrade. Mostly it has been some refactoring of the core code to make it more efficient, though there have been some additions and changes that enable you to take advantage of newer reporting capabilities and some other stuff for tracking (which is kind of irrelevant if you aren't planning on changing your implementation).

Sidnote: I kind of wonder why you're second guessing your Adobe Consultant, in the first place though.. is it an Adobe ClientCare rep, or is it some 3rd party consultant? If it's the latter, perhaps this is an indication to find a new consultant!

Comment: Thanks Crayon Violent!

Comment: gotta love how the release notes are hidden behind a login screen.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider: the implementation of the s.tl() method has changed a bit lately to accommodate changes in Webkit based browsers (Safari & Chrome) as well as Firefox.

If you are using Custom Link Tracking, you should thoroughly test that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that, go through all the custom reports (traffic, conversion and event reports) and see if there are any major deviations in the data. Or just set up an alerts for the reports (on most of the metrics) for any major deviations.

Mostly, there will not be any errors while upgrading, however, you might have written some custom plugins in the old library and just make sure to include all the libraries (or Javascript functions) to include in the new library.

Hope that makes sense.